# Python - Openpyxl - Searching for a string value in one column, multiple sheets. How to detect for Null, None, False in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

**Searching Excel File For String Using Openpyxl - (Python 3.10)**

I'm **searching** for a **string**, in **column A**, within **four worksheets**. The script **works** if the **cell value** is **found** within the **worksheet**.

I want to know **how to determine** if the **cell doesn't exist**? (so I can the search for using an alternative string).

**Script** (I've attached a photo of the results)

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Color, PatternFill, Font, Border
from openpyxl.styles import colors
from openpyxl.cell import Cell
import colorama
from colorama import init
init()
from colorama import Fore, Style, Back
import os
import shutil
import math
from decimal import Decimal
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment
from inspect import currentframe
import time

########################################
#########################################

src_path ="/Users/data/"
xlfileName = "test.xlsx"
xlfile = src_path + xlfileName
wb = Workbook()
wb = load_workbook(xlfile)

#########################################
#########################################

def get_linenumber():
    cf = currentframe()
    return cf.f_back.f_lineno

#########################################
#########################################

#########################################
#########################################

for xws in wb.sheetnames:
    worksheet = wb[xws]
    print(Style.RESET_ALL)
    print(Fore.BLUE, "Looping Through Worksheet Name -- ", worksheet, "Script line is -- ", get_linenumber())
    print(Style.RESET_ALL)
    for cell in worksheet['A']:
        search_string33 = "Current debt"  #
        search_string34 = "test"  #
        try:
            if search_string33 == cell.value:
                offset_colB_CD = cell.offset(row=0, column=1)
                print(Fore.RED, ( "Line 52 -- worksheet -- ", worksheet, "Searching for --", search_string33, "isinstance --", isinstance(search_string33, type(None))))
                if(offset_colB_CD.coordinate is None):
                    print("Line 54 -- null value detected in -- ", worksheet)
                elif(offset_colB_CD.coordinate is not None):
                    print(Fore.LIGHTRED_EX, "Line 56 -- worksheet -- ", worksheet," -- cell cordinate found --", offset_colB_CD.coordinate, " -- cell value found --", offset_colB_CD.value )
                    print(Style.RESET_ALL)
                else:
                    print("Line 59 if statement passed by on else")
                time.sleep(5)
        except (AttributeError, TypeError):
            continue
```

[image: string search openpyxl]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer To Question**

In my initial question, I failed to view **the number of elements** being directly queried in the column. As such if a direct hit was not attained, it moved on. I could n**ot use 'None'**, because, it had **other elements present**.

The best option was to **build a list** and then **filter** through the list to see if it **contained** the string. If it does contain the string invoke **first** choice command, and if not invoke **alternative** command.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Color, PatternFill, Font, Border
from openpyxl.styles import colors
from openpyxl.cell import Cell
import colorama
from colorama import init
init()
from colorama import Fore, Style, Back
import os
import shutil
import math
from decimal import Decimal
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment
from inspect import currentframe
import time

########################################
#########################################

src_path ="/Users/data/"
xlfileName = "test.xlsx"
xlfile = src_path + xlfileName
wb = Workbook()
wb = load_workbook(xlfile)

#########################################
#########################################

def get_linenumber():
    cf = currentframe()
    return cf.f_back.f_lineno

#########################################
#########################################

#########################################
#########################################

for xws in wb.sheetnames:
    worksheet = wb[xws]
    print(Style.RESET_ALL)
    print(Fore.BLUE, "Looping Through Worksheet Name -- ", worksheet, "Script line is -- ", get_linenumber())
    print(Style.RESET_ALL)
    search_string33 = "Current debt"  #
    search_string34 = "Total current liabilities"
    cell_list = []
    for cell in worksheet['A']:
        cell_list.append(cell.value)
    number_of_elements = len(cell_list)
    print("Number of elements in the list: ", number_of_elements)
    if search_string33 in cell_list :
        print(Fore.GREEN, "Yes -- ", search_string33)
        print(Style.RESET_ALL)
    elif search_string33 not in cell_list and search_string34 in cell_list:
        print(Fore.LIGHTMAGENTA_EX, "No -- ", search_string33, Fore.GREEN, "Yes -- ", search_string34)
        print(Style.RESET_ALL)
    elif search_string33 not in cell_list and search_string34 not in cell_list:
        print(Fore.RED, "Mother of Holy Crap", search_string33)
        print(Style.RESET_ALL)
```

[image: string match excel via python]

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution I can think about is iterating through a list of the strings in the order you want to search for them.

Example:

```py
search_strings = ["Current debt", "test"]

for xws in wb.sheetnames:
    worksheet = wb[xws]
    print(Style.RESET_ALL)
    print(Fore.BLUE, "Looping Through Worksheet Name -- ", worksheet, "Script line is -- ", get_linenumber())
    print(Style.RESET_ALL)

    current_search_index = 0
    found_cell = False
    for current_string in search_strings:
        for cell in worksheet['A']:
            try:
                if current_string == cell.value:
                    offset_colB_CD = cell.offset(row=0, column=1)
                    print(Fore.RED, ( "Line 52 -- worksheet -- ", worksheet, "Searching for --", current_string, "isinstance --", isinstance(current_string, type(None))))
                    if(offset_colB_CD.coordinate is None):
                        print("Line 54 -- null value detected in -- ", worksheet)
                    elif(offset_colB_CD.coordinate is not None):
                        print(Fore.LIGHTRED_EX, "Line 56 -- worksheet -- ", worksheet," -- cell cordinate found --", offset_colB_CD.coordinate, " -- cell value found --", offset_colB_CD.value )
                        print(Style.RESET_ALL)
                        found_cell = True
                    else:
                        print("Line 59 if statement passed by on else")
                    time.sleep(5)
            except (AttributeError, TypeError):
                continue
        if found_cell == False:
            current_search_index += 1
        else:
            break
    if found_cell == False:
        print(Fore.RED, "Line 67 -- ", current_string, "not found in -- ", worksheet)
        print(Style.RESET_ALL)
```

Comment: Until the script can detect which worksheets do not have the value in column A, it cannot move to onto the next step.

Comment: Have a look at my edit. Is this what you meant? If it cannot find the value, it will print it out, and you can break, or do anything you want with it.

Comment: It did work, but doing it this way would mean more lines of code. I was looking to do everything within one loop per sheet. I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to do it in one loop, it won't work like you explained before. I don't think what you want is possible without "more lines of code" (which is not a bad thing in my opinion anyways)

Comment: I answered my question :o)

Answer (score 0):

`worksheet.values` will return a list of tuples. At which point we can reduce our list using list comprehension and filtering.

```py
matching_strs = ['Current_debt', 'test']
matches = [{'ws':ws, 'row_num':row_num, 'row':row} for ws in wb.worksheets for row_num, row in enumerate(ws.values) if row[0] in matching_strs]
```

This will return a list of dicts, with the attributes of ws, row_num, row. Which should provide all of the info that you would need to print out the results.

No need for the `( )` around the `if` tests.

To print the results just loop and test

```py
for match in matches:
    # Return position [1] is the equivalent of column B
    # since indexing starts at 0.
    if match['row'][1]:
        print( Match found... )
```

Comment: I tried to match, openpyxl was throwing errors. best option was to build a list then approach to see if the list contained the string.

Comment: ok - as long as you have something that works. I'd need an error message to help beyond that.

Comment: Since I can't comment on your solution, I want to point a few things out: `for xws in wb.sheetnames` are you sure you can't call wb.worksheets ? This is already provided for you.   Also, with the `elif` statements. You don't have to test 'search_str33 not in cell_list' this is known, since it failed the first `if` test.